# codeigniter apache rewrite rule for static directory

Tags: regex, apache, codeigniter, apache2, webserver

I have the rewrite rule for codeigniter at my webhost:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|static|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^[css|js|fonts](/.*)?$ /static$1 [L]
```

I have a static folder which I want to have accessed through domain/static/css/Layout.css where codeigniter shouldn't parse at 1st.

I am not a regex expert, therefor I am asking you all for your advise. I would kindly thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The 4th line is not needed.

Try removing 4th line and changing 3rd line to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hallo Mohammad!

I need 2 regular expressions!

everything with CSS/*,JS/* and fonts/* should point to => /static/css/*, /static/js/* and /static/fonts/*

and everything else to:

/index.php/*

Comment: Oh! I didn't notice that you don't want `static` to appear in your url. Sorry, I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

Here it is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/static/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(css|img|fonts|js)$ /static/$1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|static)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```